# MVC sidebar responsive issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, sidebar

I'm using a template found https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar (it's the 2nd sidebar option). I have it integrated into a stock MVC5 application and everything works except for whatever is in RenderBody(), it's not responsive to when the sidebar is toggled open/closed. It is responsive when I resize the page, and the sidebar responds appropriately too, but I don't want the sidebar to overlay the contents on RenderBody(). How would I go about fixing that? Thank you in advanced!

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content Holder -->
        <div id="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!--
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "minimal"
            });

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
                $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Site.css

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #367fa9;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #367fa9;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #3c8dbc;
}


a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}


ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #3c8dbc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#content.active {
    width: 100%;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content.active {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
    }

    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thank you for the correction. I didn't realize there was a better tag to use.